# How to Retrieve value of SUM group by in SQL through c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have following SQL query which works well in SQL, I tried a lot to get sum result in c# label but still unable to do it, need some kind guide from Gurus of C# n SQL.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE getdays
    @tr_ptr nvarchar(6),
    @tr_din nvarchar(2),
    @Total int output
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Total = SUM (CONVERT(int, tr_din))
    FROM Treatments 
    GROUP BY tr_ptr
END
```

Code trying to use this in C#:

```
public void Days()
{
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "getdays";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tr_ptr");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tr_din");
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", year);

    var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@total", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    int total = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

getting errors but no result.

Comment: If you get an error, it would help if you post the error message.

Comment: Just getting red line under AddWithValue asking for an argument which is not avail .

Comment: You aren't using either of those parameters in your procedure. Why are they even there?

Comment: I used it with some different criteria in my program where the parameters were avail but here I am so much confused that how I call the store procedure here without parameters, please guide me or recode it for me so I can use it my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an **output parameter** - not the return value.

And since you're storing the value from the `SELECT` into the output parameter, no rows are being returned from the `SELECT`, so you cannot use `ExecuteScalar()` but need to use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead

```
public int GetDays()
{
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "getdays";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // don't use "AddWithValue" - explicitly specify data type of parameters like this
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tr_ptr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 6).Value = ".....";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@tr_din", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2).Value = "..";

    // use an "Output" parameter - not "return value"    
    var outputParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@total", SqlDbType.Int);
    outputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    con.Open();

    // since no dataset is returned - use ExecuteNonQuery
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    int total = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameter.Value);
    con.Close();

    return total;
}
```

Comment: I did it as per your guide and getting this error ::: cannot implicitly convert type object to int. An explicit (are you missing a cast)conversation exists   at botom of code outputParameter.Value; with a redline.   and   at return total: it under redline saying .... a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: @Riaz: updated my response - try: `int total = Convert.ToInt32(outputParameter.Value);`

Comment: I am again posting my code according to your guidelines. now it is not giving me any error. But there is no out put at label AcPtVisitLbl.Text   .. Please review it one more time.

Answer (score 0):

As per guidelines of marc_s I did it as follow. marc_s please review it. no error no output result in the following line of code.

```
public void Days()
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Treatments where tr_ptr='" + AcPtPtrDd.Text.ToString() + "'", con);

            cmd.CommandText = "getdays";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tr_ptr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 6).Value = ".....";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tr_din", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2).Value = "..";
            var outputParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@total", SqlDbType.Int);
            outputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //int total = Convert.ToUInt32(outputParameter.Value);// showing error
            string total = outputParameter.Value.ToString();
            con.Close();
            AcPtVisitLbl.Text = total;
            //return total;
        }
```

Comment: I changed ' int total ' to ' string total ' because the data in the column was in nvarchar .

Comment: Have you debugged through?? Do you get any value back in the `outputParameter` ?? Of course, if nothing is returned - then you won't get anything displayed - but that really depends on your data in the table - I cannot possibly tell you this from here...... you need to **debug** and see for yourself ....